# Error 404 getJson retrieving a local json file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to load a Json file, in the same folder of my script using the `CodeIgniter` and `$.getJson`.

I have already tried changing the .htaccess content in the root directory of my site and in the application folder, changing the loading route to

```
.$getJson("<?php echo base_url...")
```

and NOTHING worked. It always shows the same error:

> jquery.min.js:4 GET
>   http://www.my-site.com/index.php/admin_cotrol/shop_list.json
>   404 (Not Found)

Here is my script:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        var output = '<div class="row">';
        var count = 1;
        $.getJSON("shop_list.json", function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                if ((val.name.search(regex) != -1) || (val.location.search(regex) != -1)) {
                    output += '<div class="col-md-6 well">';
                        output += '<div class="col-md-7">';
                            output += '<h5>' + val.productName + '</h5>';
                            output += '<p>' + val.productPrice + '</p>'
                            output += '<p>' + val.ProductDiscount + '</p>'
                        output += '</div>';
                    output += '</div>';
                    if(count%2 == 0) {
                        output += '</div><div class="row">'
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            });
            output += '</div>';
            $('#show_results').html(output);
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Where have you placed the JSON file in folder hierarchy ?

Comment: @squiroid I placed the script and the json archive in the same folder. The root folder

Comment: Then why it is not accessible via the URL that you have given ?.

 http://www.my-site.com/index.php/admin_cotrol/shop_list.json

Comment: I cant access it too

Comment: use base path to access file `<?php echo base_url()/folder/shop_list.json ?>`

Comment: @NishantNair it doesn't work. It gets the things worst

Answer (score 1):

Suggest moving the file to a new directory off of your root.

Ex: 
/static/json/shop_list.json

Then you will able to access using:

```
$.getJSON("/static/shop_list.json", function(data) {
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Now shows me this error: http:/www.my-site.com/test_things/files_list.json 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

First of all put your json file in root having assets folder..i.e `assets/shop_list.json`.Then make a controller in `application/controller` having function `loadjson()` save as `Json.php`

```
class Json extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url'); //loads url helper
    }

    public function loadjson()
    {
        $this->load->view('json');
    }
}
```

Inside `application/views` create view `json.php` having script...

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var url = "<?php echo base_url('assets/shop_list.json');?>";
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        var output = '<div class="row">';
        var count = 1;
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                if ((val.name.search(regex) != -1) || (val.location.search(regex) != -1)) {
                    output += '<div class="col-md-6 well">';
                        output += '<div class="col-md-7">';
                            output += '<h5>' + val.productName + '</h5>';
                            output += '<p>' + val.productPrice + '</p>'
                            output += '<p>' + val.ProductDiscount + '</p>'
                        output += '</div>';
                    output += '</div>';
                    if(count%2 == 0) {
                        output += '</div><div class="row">'
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            });
            output += '</div>';
            $('#show_results').html(output);
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves my main problem. But now another appers, no, search results retrieved. But thank you a lot.

Comment: `console.log(data);` may be in json format..so you have to `JSON.parse(data)` first to convert into object.

Comment: Now it throws me a different error code, but bassically is the same. I do exactly what you suggest me, and it has the same mistake. GET http://www.my-site.com/assets/shop_list.json 404 (Not Found)

Comment: please help me again

Comment: if you have not manage `.htaccess` then url must be `var url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/assets/shop_list.json');?>";`